# Flutter ScrollablePositionedList not able jumpTo Index issue

Tags: flutter, listview, scrollview, scroll-position

I apply ScrollablePositionedList, but it doesn't work. When I click on the number, it did not jump to the index.

Below are the sample images that I want to achieve.
[image]

When I clicked number 10, it should jump to Item 10 as below (here the list of numbers on the top should be scroll up as well and not visible):

[image]

However, when I click on the number it does not jump to the index.
Below are the code. I guess there is something wrong with my code, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
  ItemScrollController controller = ItemScrollController();

  return Column(
    children: [
      Text("Click the number below to jump to Index"),
      Wrap(
        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < totalItems; i++)
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  controller.jumpTo(index: index);
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    (i).toString(),
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                )
              )
        ],
      ),
      ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemScrollController: controller,
          itemCount: totalItems.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 200),
              child: Container(
                color: Color.fromARGB(
                    255,
                    Random().nextInt(255),
                    Random().nextInt(255),
                    Random().nextInt(255)),
                height: 100.0 * index * 0.1,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    "Item $index",
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```dart
for (int i = 0; i < totalItems; i++)
            InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  controller.jumpTo(index: index);
                },
```

You haven't shared what `index` is, but the key problem should be with it.

As you can see, your looping over `totalItems` and for each item, we have the variaiable `i`. But you aren't using `i`, you are using `index` instead.

So, make use of `i`:

```dart
 InkWell(
    onTap: () {
 controller.jumpTo(index: i);
 },
```

**Complete runnable example:**

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/scrollable_positioned_list.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TestApp());
}

class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final totalItems = List.generate(100, (index) => index);
  ItemScrollController controller = ItemScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("Click the number below to jump to Index"),
        Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < totalItems.length; i++)
              InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    controller.jumpTo(index: i);
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      (i).toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ))
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
              itemScrollController: controller,
              itemCount: totalItems.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints:
                      const BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 200),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, Random().nextInt(255),
                        Random().nextInt(255), Random().nextInt(255)),
                    height: 100.0 * index * 0.1,
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        "Item $index",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```